# PDFBox on Heroku - Rendering PDF - Standard Fonts not available

Tags: pdf, heroku, fonts, render, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to render thumbnails of PDF documents on Heroku. The PDFs I use to test my code render fine locally on a Mac, on Heroku certain fonts don't render.

I suspect that PDFBox can't find the 14 Standard Fonts. I could include them in my app, but I couldn't figure out how to tell PDFBox where to search for the fonts.

Before I dig deeper in the internals of PDFBox, maybe somebody knows an easy way to fix this?

Comment: All fonts that are not embedded in the PDF.